# Installing psycopg2 module in cpanel without root acces?

Tags: python, linux, cpanel, psycopg2

I'm trying to get Psycopg2 installed on a remote server (AcuGIS) through Cpanel but I don't have root access. I found [this](https://www.acugis.com/members/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=345) documentation on installing the module, but can't seem to figure out how to accomplish it.

Is this even possible without root access, if so how?